# Gesture Swipe - Storyboard Segue

Tags: ios, gesture, uiswipegesturerecognizer

Been reading up on Gesture swiping and how to push on or off UIViews depending on the direction. I just to have come to an issue that I haven't been able to work out. I can recognise the touch events  i.e. up, down, left, right. However when I try to segue to another screen (within the storyboard) I receive an error that is so vague I'm not sure where to begin. I have seen other apps do this so clearly it can be done, just have not found the correct tut or example. Below is the code if anyone had an idea.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
```

{
    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeUp = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(didSwipe:)];
    swipeUp.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
    swipeUp.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionUp;
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:swipeUp];

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeDown = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(didSwipe:)];
swipeDown.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
swipeDown.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionDown;
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:swipeDown];

UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeLeft = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(didSwipe:)];
swipeLeft.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
swipeLeft.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:swipeLeft];

UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeRight = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(didSwipe:)];
swipeRight.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
swipeRight.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight;
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:swipeRight];

[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
```

//    [self.view removeGestureRecognizer:swipeUp];
//    [self.view removeGestureRecognizer:swipeDown];
//    [self.view removeGestureRecognizer:swipeLeft];
//    [self.view removeGestureRecognizer:swipeRight];
}

```
FirstViewController *fvc;
-(void)didSwipe: (UISwipeGestureRecognizer *) sender
{
    UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection direction = sender.direction;

    switch (direction)
    {
        case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight:
            NSLog(@"you swiped the screen right");
            [self performSelector:@selector(goRight:)];
            break;

        case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft:
            NSLog(@"you swiped the screen left");
            [self performSelector:@selector(goLeft:)];
            break;

        case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionDown:
            NSLog(@"you swiped down");
            //[self performSelector:@selector(goDown:)];
            break;

        case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionUp:
            NSLog(@"you swiped Up");
            //[self performSelector:@selector(goUp:)];
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
}

-(void)goRight:(id)sender
{
    UIStoryboard* storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"ip5" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    UIViewController* controller = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"FirstView"];
    controller.transitioningDelegate  = self;
    [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: Can you show the error? BTW why don't you use a simple perform segue ? is that a different Storyboard ?

Comment: Hi Shannoga, Yeah trying to recreate the error as I was typing this message. Normal segue works okay but when you go to the previous screen it aborts. I think it has something to do with identifying where it has come from i.e. the previous screen, next screen scenario. I'll post the error as soon as I can redo it again.

Comment: Error Received: Thread 1:EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=2, Address=0x100)

This happens when you gesture your finger in the correct direction but then go back. I think I may need to create a new .h/.m class for each view that I want to manipulate then tell the view where it came from and where its going to. I think....

Comment: Error Received: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid parameter not satisfying: [identifier length] > 0'

A common trait I'm seeing is that if you gesture any direction > 3 times then it fails. I think it needs to be released somehow...

Comment: Can you try to remove the Gesture Recogniser right after any swipe is detected ?

Comment: How so? Within the function itself?

Comment: Yes, just for the test call removeGestureRecognizer at the begging of goRight or any other method that you test